# Is this a google cloud build bug? or am I doing Docker wrong?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, google-cloud-build

First question is 'does anyone know what i am doing wrong below?'.  Second question is 'If no, is there a way to list files in some kind of command that I put in the Dockerfile hoping to debug more, and perhaps do a pwd in the Dockerfile too(trying to see what is different in each environment'

Step 1. git checkout master, git pull

Step 2. Run "gcloud builds submit --config cloudbuild.yaml"

Step 3. Have a google build trigger setup using the 'same exact' cloudbuild.yaml from the repo

Step 4. "gcloud alpha builds triggers run default-push-trigger-1 --branch master"

Step 2 succeeds and properly runs the entry point of Docker image.  Step 4. fails with

```
/bin/sh: ./downloadAndExtract.sh: not found
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/orderly-gcp/continuous-deploy" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 127
```

My Dockerfile is very simple

FROM gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:alpine

```
RUN mkdir -p ./monobuild
COPY . ./monobuild/
WORKDIR "/monobuild"
ENTRYPOINT ./downloadAndExtract.sh
```

My cloudbuild.yaml file is even more simple

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/continuous-deploy
```

Are there any environment issues or something?

I run the docker build/push cycle in a directory with these files

- Dockerfile
- cloudbuild.yaml
- deployDockerImage.sh
- downloadAndExtract.sh
- runCILocallyToTest.sh
- triggerGoogleRemoteBuild.sh

OF COURSE, the ONLY two files needed in that directory are Dockerfile and downloadAndExtract.sh so I should probably change my docker file to just copy downloadAndExtract.  Anyways, that's not the important piece.  Why is google build triggers not working for me?

EDIT: I just had an epiphany.  Put ls as the entrypoint.  This proved that the async trigger is corrupting my build image with my mono repo contents and blowing away anything I had setup.  Why is this?  Why would they make the sync kick off a build different than a built trigger?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is several mistakes in your Dockerfile

First, the path definition

```
COPY . ./monobuild/
WORKDIR "/monobuild"
```

You copy your file in the `<currentPath>/monobuild` (I mean `./monobuild`), and you define your workdir as `<rootPath>/monobuild`.

Thus, the entrypoint use the `./downloadAndExtract.sh` which is normally into `<rootPath>/monobuild`.

So, for sanitizing your Dockerfile, I propose this

```
RUN mkdir -p /monobuild
WORKDIR "/monobuild"
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT /monobuild/downloadAndExtract.sh
```

Does it make sense in your context? Does it work?

Comment: I found out the cryptic error was if someone moves the cloudbuild.yaml in your repo, it gives you   the cryptic error and the trigger stops working so it ended up having nothing to do with the docker file.  +1 to your answer though for trying still so thanks!!! It's appreciated!.